# How to create routes from anchor tags from react router without the # in the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a single page in my application with several sections which can be scrolled. I want to use React Router to create links to these sections. I want them to be real links without the `#`. Exactly what they have done in the `react-router` documentation (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). In there, the sidebar links doesn't use anchor tags like `#about`. Instead, they use regular links which get mapped to the anchor tags. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of Routers included with `react-router`, if you want the html5 push state version with no anchor tags, then you would use [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter).

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter
  basename={optionalString}
  forceRefresh={optionalBool}
  getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
  keyLength={optionalNumber}>
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

--

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar"/>
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

---

If you wanted to use the anchor tag routing, then you would use [`HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)

Comment: In your example, does `<a href="/calendar/today">` link to an anchor tag `#today`. HashRouter does add a # to the url right?

Comment: yes, if you see in the docs for HashRouter the example it shows that a `<Link>` will render with the `#` --  [`<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="#/calendar/today"`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)